# How to exit psql depending on the outcome of a query

Tags: postgresql, psql

```
cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin
psql.exe -v v1="test" -h localhost -d postgres -U postgres -p 5432 -a -q -f  /elan/Validate_files.sql
....

Select case when current_date-date(a.timestamp_1) >1 then 'No' Else 'Yes' End as Check
from elan.temp_file_names a
where a.filename not in (select b.filename from elan.temp_previous_names b)
and position('ELAN_CLAIMS' in a.filename)>1 order by timestamp_1 desc

\gset
```

If Check is No, I want to end the psql process, how do I do that?

Comment: What do want to do when check is "Yes", or if some are "yes" and some are "no"?

Comment: It is the only location where the test exists. The first part of the SQL checks a remote sFTP server for new files, If there are new files (Yes) then I will continue on with the rest of the SQL programming. If the answer is (No), I just wan to end the PSQL statement (Validate_files.sql)

Comment: Select case when current_date-date(a.timestamp_1) >1 then 'False' Else 'True' End as Check
from elan.temp_file_names a
where a.filename not in (select b.filename from elan.temp_previous_names b)
and position('ELAN_CLAIMS' in a.filename)>1 order by timestamp_1 desc

\gset
\IF :check
psql:/elan/Validate_files.sql:37: error: invalid command \IF

Comment: I tried the /IF statement as shown above, but the PSQL doesn't recognize the \IF

Comment: psql:/elan/Validate_files.sql:37: error: invalid command \IF

Comment: I ran the following in PSQL and I get an error that \IF is invalid

Select case when current_date-date(a.timestamp_1) >1 then '0' Else '1' End as Check
from elan.temp_file_names a
where a.filename not in (select b.filename from elan.temp_previous_names b)
and position('ELAN_CLAIMS' in a.filename)>1 order by timestamp_1 desc;
 check
-------
 0
(1 row)


\gset


 \IF :check = 1
psql:/elan/Validate_files.sql:40: error: invalid command \IF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `CASE` expression to return a `boolean`:

```
CASE WHEN ... THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE
END AS check ... \gset
```

Then use `\if`:

```
\if :check
\q
\endif
```

Comment: Why do I continue to get the invalid command /IF error?

Comment: I am running Version 12

Comment: --If no new files today, end process

 Select case when current_date-date(a.timestamp_1) >1 then TRUE Else FALSE End as Check
 from elan.temp_file_names a
 where a.filename not in (select b.filename from elan.temp_previous_names b)
 and position('ELAN_CLAIMS' in a.filename)>1 order by timestamp_1 desc;
  check
 -------
  t
 (1 row)

 \gset

 \echo :check
 t

  \IF :check
 psql:/elan/Validate_files.sql:40: error: invalid command \IF

Comment: Looks like a bad semicolon before `\gset`.

Comment: Try the right way instead. In the mangled comment above, you have `order by timestamp_1 desc; ` There is a semicolon in this. That is wrong. Your original code in the question was right.